# Opening a facebook URL on iOS with openURL leads to broken page on Facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook

When I open a facebook url using 'openURL', in the form of "http://www.facebook.com/SomePage", it gets opened by the Facebook app, and it leads to a broken page (most of the screen is blank), or to the user's "timeline" (depending on the device and version of the app). Is there any way to force the URL to go to Safari? I don't mind that the facebook app takes over the URL, but if it doesn't know how to handle it, I'd rather have Safari do it.

Comment: I am having the same issue Instead of redirecting to safari my app send user to Facebook app. it only happens in Iphone 5. previous all version device work fine with the app.

Comment: I think there is more to it than just going to the Facebook app.   It seems like there is some GOOFY stuff going on with app schemes specifically surrounding facebook links that start with 'www'.  I have cases on test devices where following such a link goes to random other app schemes.    However, the same link without 'www' goes correctly to Safari.   Weird.

Comment: @pj4533, perhaps you should answer this question with the above answer so it can be marked correct. It also worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

As pj4533 suggested, removing the 'www.' from the front of the url fixes the issue. Adding this as an answer so it can be marked as answer and more obvious for others.

Comment: As of Sept 2013, this bug remains - and the www needs to be removed from URL's. Annoying - but thank you so much for the fix!

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug/feature with the latest facebook app, when you use the url with shortname it instead opens the last page or the news feed of the user.  You need to use the user/group id.

You can find it using the graph API https://graph.facebook.com/SHORT_NAME under the propertie "id"

example :

```
https://www.facebook.com/stackoverflowpage
https://www.facebook.com/11239244970
```

just paste page URL here http://findmyfacebookid.com/ and you will get ID for page.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know does this work for you, because it is working fine for me...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.facebook.com/"]];
```